# How to use Search functionality in mvc controller with searchstring

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to implement search functionality in controller method but I got as i am not able to use "Get" clause, it throws and type conversion error. I get error at

> getAll = getAll.Content.Where(a => a.Firstname.Contains(searchString) || a.Lastname.Contains(searchString));

.controller method

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(UserViewModel userVM)
    {
        
        var userData = await _userSessionCache.GetUserSessionWithUserIdAsync();
        var tenantClientId = userData.TenantClientId;
        var getAll = await _userApiService.GetAll(tenantClientId);
        var searchString = userVM.SearchString;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            getAll = getAll.Content.Where(a => a.Firstname.Contains(searchString) || a.Lastname.Contains(searchString));
        }
        if (!getAll.IsSuccessful)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Unable to get User Data");
        }

        var dataList = getAll.Content;
        var vm = new UserViewModel();
        vm.SetUser(dataList);
        return View(vm);
    }
```

.cs

Task<ApiResponse<List>> GetAll(Guid tenantClientId);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getAll -> ApiResponse<List>
getAll.Content  -> List 
getAll.Content.Where(...) -> IEnumerable
```

So you try to

```
ApiResponse<List> getAll = IEnumerable;
```

you have a type conversion error because `IEnumerable` can't be casted to `ApiResponse<List>`.

You should try use List variable:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(UserViewModel userVM)
{
    
    var userData = await _userSessionCache.GetUserSessionWithUserIdAsync();
    var tenantClientId = userData.TenantClientId;
    var getAll = await _userApiService.GetAll(tenantClientId);
    var searchString = userVM.SearchString;
    
    if (!getAll.IsSuccessful)
    {
        throw new System.Exception("Unable to get User Data");
    }        

    var dataList = getAll.Content;

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        dataList = dataList
              .Where(a => a.Firstname.Contains(searchString) || 
                                a.Lastname.Contains(searchString))
              .ToList();
    }

    var vm = new UserViewModel();
    vm.SetUser(dataList);
    return View(vm);
}
```